# Asp.net MVC4 Web API XML serialization ignores public properties

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I'm using asp.net mvc4 web api. I've got some classes generated by Devart Entity Developer and they have following structure:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Test")]
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute("property1")]
    [JsonProperty("property1")]
    public int Property1
    {
        get { return _Property1; }
        set
        {
            if (_Property1 != value)
            {
                _Property1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private int _Property1;

    [XmlAttribute("property2")]
    [JsonProperty("property2")]
    public int Property2
    {
        get { return _Property2; }
        set
        {
            if (_Property2 != value)
            {
                _Property2 = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private int _Property2;
}
```

I have test controller for such class:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private List<Test> _tests = new List<Test>() ;

    public TestController()
    {
        _tests.Add(new Test() { Property1 = 1, Property2 = 2 });
        _tests.Add(new Test() { Property1 = 3, Property2 = 4 });
    }

    public IEnumerable<Test> Get()
    {
        return _tests;
    }
}
```

When I try to get test values in JSON format it returns correct response:

```
"[{"property1":1,"property2":2},{"property1":3,"property2":4}]"
```

But when I use XML format it serializes not public (`Property1`) but private properties (i.e. `_Property1`) and response look like:

```
<ArrayOfTest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestProject.Models.Data">
  <Test>
     <_Property1>1</_Property1>
     <_Property2>2</_Property2>
   </Test>
   <Test>
     <_Property1>3</_Property1>
     <_Property2>4</_Property2>
   </Test>
</ArrayOfTest>
```

**UPD:** I've tried to add [NonSerialized] and [XmlIgnore] to private properties, but in this way xml output was empty, just:

```
<ArrayOfTest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PeopleAirAPI.Models.Data">
  <Test/>
  <Test/>
</ArrayOfTest>
```

The question is how to force xml serializator to serialize public properties. To hide (ignore) that private properties is not a problem. I can't understand why it serializes that private properties at all, I've read in msdn docs and in other places that:

> XML serialization only serializes public fields and properties.

Why in this case it acts contrary to docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web API uses DataContractSerializer instead of XmlSerializer by default, which looks at `[Serializable]` and serializes all fields before looking at anything else.

It looks like your type was designed to be serialized using XmlSerializer. I would suggest adding the following line:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

This will ensure all the public properties get serialized and all the XML serialization attributes, like `[XmlAttribute]` get respected.

Comment: I've tried to add something like [DataMember(Name = "property1")] to show serializer that those properties should be serialized, but it not helped. Your solution with `config.Formatters` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to put `[XmlIgnore]` on the `private long _Id;`

Comment: That was first  thing I've tried. In this way Xml output is empty: `<MyClass></MyClass>`